# NodeJs helmet hsts configuration

Tags: node.js, express

I'm not super familiar with NodeJs but have been asked to support a NodeJs app for perceived security vulnerability.  I'm using a Express web server on NodeJs.  The requirement is to use hsts.  So I installed the helmet module and added the following code:

app.use(helmet.hsts());

I believe hsts module will force the client to make connection over https and will not support connections over http.

Question:  Does it mean that that now that NodeJs express server has to be given an SSL certificate.

Qu

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this, but this is not a requirement.
If you want to do it like that import `https` and create the server from that instead of `http`:

```js
const app = require('express')();
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

// ...

https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.pem'),
    passphrase: 'YOUR PASSPHRASE'
}, app)
.listen(443);
```

Another popular solution would be to still run your application with plain HTTP but then use a proxy (e.g. NGINX, HAProxy or Apache) in front of it to do the SSL and make the connection to the client.

E.g. this here is an example for NGINX (application runs on http://localhost:3000)

```
server {

    listen 443;
    server_name yourhost.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/cert.key;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://localhost:3000;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      http://localhost:3000 https://yourhost.domain.com;
    }
  }
```